# Rollback previous transaction when current transaction is failed within Spring RepositoryEventHandler

Tags: spring, microservices, event-driven

I have two entities (**ABC and PQR**) and there is an updating operation going on. ABC entity updating is done within **@RepositoryEventHandler** classes (**ABCEntityHandler**) and after the ABC entity is updated, I need **PQR** entity to be updated based on ABC entity information. That part is done within the **ABCEntityAfterSave** method and now I am implementing a rollback mechanism where the ABC entity is required to be rollback if the **PQR** entity saving fails within **updatePQRInformation** method. I have tried with several approaches with @Transactional annotation but did not work here. Any idea on how to do this within **RepositoryEventHandler** class with the help of spring

PS - The database is not relational. Its mongo DB and it is mandatory to have 2 transactions. cannot be done within 1 transaction

```
@RepositoryEventHandler
public class ABCEntityHandler {

    @Autowired
    private PQRService pqrService;


    @HandleBeforeSave
    public void ABCEntityBeforeSave(ABC abc) {
       log.debug("before save ABC");
    }

    @HandleAfterSave
    public void ABCEntityAfterSave(ABC abc) {
       log.debug("after save ABC");

       pqrService.updatePQRInformation(abc);
    }
}
```

=============

```
@Service
public class PQRService {

  @Autowired
  private PQRRepository pqrRepository;

  public updatePQRInformation(ABC abc) {
    PQR pqr = new PQR();
    pqr.setName(abs.getName());
    pqr.setAge(abs.getAge());

    // expect to thrown an runtime exception here
    pqrRepository.save(pqr);
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot rollback a committed transaction. Jus store everything in a single transaction.

Comment: here the issue is the database is not relational. Its mongo DB. So definitely it should be 2 transactions

Comment: You might want to clarify that in your question as that isn't clear from your question. Regardless, something that is comiitted cannot be rolledback. You will have to create a compensating transaction (i.e undo the previous change manually).